# How to reference a local php file to connect to mysql server?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I do not have a server to host this php file on but I want to use it with my app to connect to a mysql database. This is kinda what I am asking, this is just for testing purposes: This is within an AsyncTask

```
String link = "file://../../../../../res/mysql/testconnect.php?username="+username+"& password="+password;

URL url = new URL(link);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(URI.from(link));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: As far as I know you need a server (Apache, Nginx, etc) in order to interpret the PHP file. now about the Mysql DB where is the DB itself located? in an external server? why not use the same server for that purpose? how about using sqlite instead?

Comment: For testing PHP files, you must put that into Localhost. Did you have putted your file in htdocs folder? If yes, you need to open it in link as, http://localhost/yourfilename.php

Later if you have hosted this file to server, then you can change the url.

Comment: so I will have to make an apache server just to test this